# Handling nested observables using mergeMap and passing params to child subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like to apply with proper way nested observables

I have to observables and I would use the outer observable response and use it in the child observable

```
this.selectedSchedulings$.pipe(switchMap(actualTrips => {
  return this.selectedDataByBranch$
})).subscribe(data => {
  this.trainsDatasets = this.getDatasets(data);
  return actualTrips
});
```

`SelectedDataByBranch` is an ngrx selector

```
selectedDataByBranch$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectBranchDirections, 'b1'));
```

Actually I get error `Cannot find name actualtrips`.

How can I pass params to child subscription ?

A solution is to save `actualTrips` on a global variable but I would do it cleaner.

Comment: from where are you importing switchMap operator ?

Comment: can you share the selectedDataByBranch$ observable logic ?

Comment: It's an ngrx selector, I have added it to post and yes I'm importing rxjs operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `forkJoin` in the return of the switchMap like this:

```
this.selectedSchedulings$.pipe(
   switchMap(actualTrips => 
       return forkJoin([
            this.selectedDataByBranch$,
            of(actualTrips)
       ]);
   })
).subscribe(([selectedDataByBranch, actualTrips]) => {
     this.trainsDatasets = this.getDatasets(selectedDataByBranch);
     return actualTrips;
});
```

If the selectedDataByBranch$ is a continuous observable, you may change the `forkJoin` to a `combineLatest`.

Comment: Observables are selectors from an ngrx store. does they count as continuous observables  ?

Comment: I get this error `Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` on this line `.subscribe(([selectedDataByBranch, actualTrips]) => {`

Comment: Yes, they count as countinuous so you have to use combineLatest.

Comment: It's working now I was Importing `CombineLatest` operator from the wrong place